# Elegant solution to count rolling two dice?

Tags: r

I am trying to count how many times I'll get the same results in each role of two dice in 100 times in R .I used

```
werFun <-  function() {
 return(sample(1:6,2,TRUE))
}
count <- 0
matResult <- matrix(0,100,2)
for (i in 1:nrow(matResult)) {
  matResult[i,] <- werFun()
   if(matResult[i,1]==matResult[i,2]){
    count=count+1
 }
}  
print(count)
```

Is there an elegant solution  ? .

Comment: `table(data.frame(t(replicate(100, sample(1:6, 2, TRUE)))))`

Comment: @SymbolixAU Is that a hint :) ?

Comment: or wrap that in `sum(diag( ... ))` if you want the number of times both rolls were the same

Comment: Yes. The probability of rolling the same number on two die is `1/6`. Do this 100 times and you get your answer :)

Comment: @alistaire perfect I accepted your comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To formalize my comments, you can simulate rolls with `sample` and repetitions with `replicate`. Combine the two, and you get a matrix. If you transpose and coerce that matrix to a data.frame, you can call `table` on it, which will neatly show you exactly what rolls you got:

```
set.seed(47)    # for reproducibility 

table(data.frame(t(replicate(100, sample(1:6, 2, TRUE)))))
##    X2
## X1  1 2 3 4 5 6
##   1 3 0 4 5 2 1
##   2 2 5 0 1 5 2
##   3 1 3 3 0 3 3
##   4 3 4 1 3 3 7
##   5 6 0 3 1 4 3
##   6 3 3 4 2 7 0
```

If you want the diagonal, where the dice are equal to each other, grab it by wrapping the call in `diag`:

```
diag(table(data.frame(t(replicate(100, sample(1:6, 2, TRUE))))))
## 1 2 3 4 5 6 
## 3 0 4 7 2 5
```

Sum it, and you'll get the number of rolls where the dice are equal:

```
sum(diag(table(data.frame(t(replicate(100, sample(1:6, 2, TRUE)))))))
## [1] 18
```

Note that it's resampling each time you call it, so numbers will vary unless you set the number generator seed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
matResult <- matrix(replicate(100,sample(1:6,2,TRUE)),ncol = 2,byrow = T)
nrow(matResult[matResult[,1]==matResult[,2],])
```

Another solution which will also work for `n` dice.

```
sum(apply(matResult,1,var)==0)
```

Comment: Thanks , that's absolutely more elegant , but I imagine the case when I roll n dice 100 times .

Answer (score 2):

You can count the times on the go if you don't really need the matrix to store all the rolling history, which could potentially save time and memory for you:

```
sum(sapply(1:100, function(i) {vec <- werFun(); vec[1] == vec[2]}))
```

Which should be essentially the same simulation process as you did. With that being said, the counter part can be simplified if you have the `matResult` already:

```
count = sum(matResult[,1] == matResult[,2])
```